csv to excelfile conversion via VBA
I'm trying to write a function which converts a csv file into an Excel file. I'm using Access 2021 and my problem is concerning the line with the Opentextfile as shown here:
Private Sub CreateExcel(strCSVPath As String, strXLSXSpath As String)
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim wb As Object

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = False

    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

    With wb.Worksheets(1)
        .Opentext strCSVPath, xlTextimportdelimited, Comma:=True
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.TexttoColumns  Destination:=.Range("A1"), dataType:=xlGeneral
    End With

    wb.SaveAs strXLSXSpath, FileFormat:=xlopenXMLWorkbook
    wb.Close Savechanges:=False
    xlApp.Quit Savechanges:=False

    Set wb = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Why not opening the csv directly, e.g. Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strCSVPath)?

Please, try this way:
Private Sub CreateExcelSess(strCSVPath As String, strXLSXSpath As String)
 Dim wb As Object

 With CreateObject("Excel.Application") 'False visibility is default
    .Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=strCSVPath, startRow:=1, DataType:=1, Comma:=True
    Set wb = .ActiveWorkbook
    wb.saveas fileName:=strXLSXSpath, FileFormat:=51 '(xlWorkbookDefault, xlOpenXMLWorkbook)
    wb.Close False
    .Quit
 End With
End Sub

Excel does not keep the csv columns saved format. So, if you have some numbers, date and want to be string or something else, you must tell us (which columns) to use another parameter dealing with format...

I tried yours as well, but my VBA doesn'T recognise xldelimited...what constant value is that?

oh I see ..its 1

@Kingsley Obeng Adapted the above code. I tested it in Excel and I forgot to use the constant value... In the meantime, I can see that you discovered it... :)

one last tging, as its just a small thing, but its costing me time....I actually have a semicolon delimiter, so I use semicolon:=True, and I try to skip the first 12 lines, but both problems are not working well...When I perform the csv to excel manually, it does it without any mistakes...

@Kingsley You also must keep DataType:=. And, of course, only one delimiter to be True. The semicolon in such a case. It should work.... If it does not keep the desired format (on columns), as I said another argument must be used (InfoField). For specific characters (other than ANSI), also Origin must be used.

OpenText is a method of the Workbooks-Collection of the Excel.Application object. With other words: You open a CSV file a new Workbook.
What your code does is it creates a blank workbook and then tries to call the method OpenText of the first worksheet of that newly created workbook. However, a worksheet has no such method - therefore the error ("Object doesn't support...").
Don't create a new workbook. Instead, use
xlApp.Workbooks.OpenText strCSVPath, xlDelimited, Comma:=True, DataType:=xlGeneral
Set wb = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook
wb.SaveAs strXLSXSpath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

Note that xlTextimportdelimited does not exist, it must be xlDelimited. To avoid such errors, always use Option Explicit.

"Set wb = Ativeworkbook" didn't work, so I assumed you mean "Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add" but then I get an error 1005 in your line : wb.SaveAs strXLSXSpath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

Sorry, must be xlApp.ActiveWorkbook - was testing directly in Excel, there you don't need to specify the Application object. Unfortunately OpenText is not a function and therefore you need to use the Active Workbook after opening the CSV file (it gets Active automatically). Corrected the code. And no, as I wrote, don't Add a new workbook - just open the CSV file.

ah ok...my "xlOpenXMLWorkbook" is empty...can I use a constant there?

Just saw that you are using late binding. In that case the constants are not defined. Yes, either switch to early binding (I would recommend that) or use numbers instead. xlOpenXMLWorkbook = 51, xlDelimited = 1 and xlGeneral = 1
